# Entropy of bivariate negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, entropy

The probability mass function (PMF) of a bivariate negative binomial distribution [1] is given by:

$$P(X=x, Y=y) = \frac{(a + x + y - 1)!}{(a-1)! x! y!} p_0^a p_1^x p_2^y $$

where $a, p_0, p_1, p_2 > 0$ and $p_0 + p_1 + p_2 = 1$.

---

I would like to calculate the entropy

$$H(x, y) = - \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} P(x, y) \log P(x, y)$$

of this distribution.

---

After some arithmetic manipulation, I arrived at the following expression:

\begin{multline}
H(x, y) = - a \log p_0 - \mathbb{E}[x] \log(p_1) - \mathbb{E}[y] \log(p_2) + \log\big((a-1)!\big) \\
- \mathbb{E}\big[\log\big((a + x + y - 1)!\big)\big] + \mathbb{E}[\log(x!)] + \mathbb{E}[\log(y!)]\end{multline}

The terms $\mathbb{E}[\log(x!)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\log(y!)]$ can be calculated by solving a definite integral in the interval $[0, 1]$ as shown in [2] (equation 23). However, it is not clear to me how the same approach can be extended for the computation of expectation of the log factorial $\mathbb{E}\big[\log\big((a + x + y - 1)!\big)\big]$ over the joint.

**Can anyone shed some light on this?**

---

References:

[1] Dunn 1967, Characterization of the Bivariate Negative Binomial Distribution ([pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84121314.pdf))

[2] Cheraghchi 2018, Expressions for the Entropy of Binomial-Type Distributions ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06394.pdf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reference [1], it says that the marginal distribution for $\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y}$ is equally simple, at the bottom of page 79. The parameters that Dunn uses for the NBin and the bivariate NBin are such that $\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y}$ is negative binomial with $p=p_1+p_2$ and $A=a$. Note in reference [2] Cheraghchi calls $A$ by $r$. Then you should be able to calculate that by using the 2nd-to-last displayed equation in [2] page 14. Take $\alpha=a$ and note that $(x+y+a-1)!$ is $\Gamma(x+y+a)$. So in that formula, that $\alpha$ should be $a$ and also that $r$ should be $a$. And $p$ should be $p_1+p_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I cannot see exactly how we can leverage the fact that $W = X + Y$ also follows a (univariate) NBin to our advantage. This is because the expectation $\mathbb{E} [\log \Gamma(x+y+a)] = \mathbb{E} [\log \Gamma(w+a)]$ is with respect to $x, y \sim P(X, Y)$ rather than $w \sim P(W) = P(X + Y)$. I might be missing something. Would you mind elaborating on this? The details of the derivation $\mathbb{E} [\log \Gamma(x+y+a)]$ would be great.

Comment: Dunn says that the marginal density is negative binomial with those parameters $p$ and $A$. I believe that means that for any function $\varphi$ if you take $\mathbf{E}[\varphi(\mathsf{X}+\mathsf{Y})]=\sum_{x,y} \varphi(x+y) \mathbf{P}(\mathsf{X}=x,\mathsf{Y}=y)$ then that is equal to $\sum_{w} \varphi(w) \mathbf{P}(\mathsf{W}=w)$ as long as the probabilities for $\mathsf{W}$ are set to be NBin with those parameters $p$ and $A$. Assuming that is true, then take the function $\varphi$ to be $\varphi(w) = \ln(\Gamma(w+\alpha))$. Then use the formula that  Cheraghchi proved.

Comment: Fantastic! I have been able to verify this numerically. It is remarkable that the equality holds for any $\varphi$ (though this is still not intuitive to me - is there any simple explanation on why that is the case?). Another important point that was useful to me is that, for the bivariate case, the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\log \Gamma(x+1)]$ is over a negative binomial with $p=\frac{p_1}{1 - p_2}$ (rather than $p=p_1$) and similarly $p=\frac{p_2}{1 - p_1}$ for $\mathbb{E}[\log \Gamma(y+1)]$. @Shannon Starr thanks again for your help!